# Double integral over circle with radius $0 \leq \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq \varepsilon$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I have the function:
$$\tag{1}
f(\eta)=-\frac{K}{\eta 8 \pi^{2}} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} d x \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \ln [1-g(\eta) \cdot(\cos x+\cos y)] d y$$
where $K$ is a constant and $g(\eta)$ given by:
$$\tag{2}
g(\eta)=\frac{\sinh (2 \eta)}{\cosh ^{2}(2 \eta)}$$

I have been given the task:

1. Expand $g(\eta)$ to second order around $\tilde{\eta}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$.
2. We assume that $x^2+y^2\ll1$. Use the expansion to get the singular contribution to $f(\eta)$ near $\tilde{\eta}$ using $\cos {x}+\cos{y} \approx 2-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)$ and performing the double integral over a circle with radius $0 \leq \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq \varepsilon$.

I did the first part, and got $g(\eta) \approx \frac{1}{2}-2[\eta-\frac{1}{2}\ln (1+\sqrt{2})]^{2}$. However, I am really in doubt about what I am expected to do for the second part. If someone can point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated.